# How do I install WSL on a Windows guest inside VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, wsl2

I am following the steps to install WSL on Windows 10 guest machine inside of VirtualBox. And currently I am facing this issue - it seems I cannot install Ubuntu Linux with WSL on a Windows 10 guest on VirtualBox.

[image: Failed to install Ubuntu]

> Installing, this may take a few minutes...
> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
> Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
> For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
> Press any key to continue...

I have also enabled "VT-x/AMD-V" with VirtualBox configuration. See below.

[image: VirtualBox config 1]

[image: VirtualBox config 2]

Please kindly help if you have any idea to solve this? Or, technically VirtualBox is currently not supporting this feature?

Comment: WSL is a form of VM. Try this Oracle Article for nesting VMs inside Virtual Box.     https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/nested-virt.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251855/virtualbox-enable-nested-vtx-amd-v-greyed-out) suggests nested virtualization with VirtualBox only is supported on AMD processors if you’re not running VirtualBox 6.1+

Comment: @John WSL1 isn't a VM so one solution if nested VMs aren't available is to switch to WSL1

Comment: WSL is a special type of VM to allow running Linux commands on a Windows Host.

Comment: @phuclv - Have doubts thats possible with WSL from the Windows Store

Comment: Also consider running VMware Workstation for the nesting you want.  Also try WSL from Microsoft from a non-Store source

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions!

Comment: The nested virtualization is grayed out, that means it’s actually disabled or specifically non-functional, and not actually enabled.